# Is there any storage limit to heroku container for free tier?

Tags: heroku, containers, cloud, hosting

Hi I am new to heroku I'm developing online IDE for this I need no install number of compilers & interpreters for it.

Comment: [Slug size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size) on Heroku can be 500 MB big. Heroku uses an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which means any files not versioned in git is lost after a restart. For that reason you should put data into a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit for [slug-size](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#slug-size) of 500 MB (*compressed*). The Slug-Size is everything from your git-repo + everything your buildpacks add (for example python runtime, or your compiler etc). By asking their support is it possible to increase that limit, though that will slow down dyno/app startup.

Due to the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) on dynos you should not store any user-data on the dynos because it will be gone after every restart/deploy.

Typically the process to create the container-image (=slug), it takes your code (=git repo), adds the runtime(s) with the buildpacks, and stores the resulting image. Following this methodology your compiler and interpreter should be added to the image via a buildpack, [which are quite easy to do yourself](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api).